# Eclipse build path missing

Tags: eclipse, git, gradle, atlassian-sourcetree

Hi I am working on a project and I have imported it via gitHub. I am importing it as a general project, it won't work otherwise. The problem I have is that there is no buildpath for the project. From java I can't run any of the files but I can run it fine in source tree with gradle.

I have read up on it and it says the way to fix it is:

> Right-click > properties > build path

That or similar options but in my eclipse there is no BUILD PATH option.

[image: Properties Menu]

---

I have tried looking at some fixes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086647/eclipse-build-path-not-available) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234399/why-does-my-eclipse-project-not-have-a-build-path). From the second link I have found that the following files are missing:

```
.classpath
.settings/*
```

Comment: You have to create a Java project to get the build path property page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the project has a gradle wrapper in the root of the project then use it to invoke the tasks `cleanEclipse eclipse` to produce the eclipse artifacts.

Assuming you're on unix type system:

```
./gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse
```

If you're on windows, use `gradlew.bat` instead.

If the GitHub project didn't have a gradle wrapper, then you can use a system version of gradle instead.

This all assumes the project has following in it. If not add it to the main build script:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

Comment: Is there a similar solution if you don't use Gradle/Maven but only use manual classpaths?

Comment: i simply wouldn't advise doing that. gradle is simple to setup for projects, but if you insist on this, i would open a new question in slack describing your build process and get solutions there rather than on this 5 year old thread